# R method to shift standard to daylight savings time by shifting entire dataset up an hour/down an hour for half the year?

Tags: r, date, datetime, dst, posixct

There are lots of questions about daylight savings conversion and posixct/posixlt, date.time, etc., but none that I have found appear to address what my approach would be to daylight savings.

I am interested in analyzing daily load curves for energy use, and approaches which just cut the spring hour out of the dataset do not work for me.  I need an approach that shifts all measurements to the subsequent hour after spring daylight savings and to the prior hour after the fall adjustment.  See below for a clear example.

```
EnergyUse <- data.table("Date"= c("1997-04-06", "1997-04-06", "1997-04-06", "1997-04-06"), "Hour"= 1:4, "Power"=c(30,40,60,80))

print(EnergyUse)
#             Date   Hour     Power
#1:     1997-04-06      1        30
#2:     1997-04-06      2        40 #when daylight savings kicked in for 1997
#3:     1997-04-06      3        60
#4:     1997-04-06      4        80
```

The "Hour" field ranges from 0 to 23 for every day of the year, i.e. "local standard time".  It happens to be Pacific Time, as you will see below, but I would have the same question for any time zone that implemented daylight savings.

Now I need to merge date and time field into single date_time field formatted as date and time and incorporating daylight savings, as I am interested in the hourly power patterns (i.e. load curves), which shift both based on relative time (e.g. when people go to/get off work) and absolute time (e.g. when it gets cold/hot or when sun sets).

```
EnergyUseAdj <- EnergyUse[, Date_Time := as.POSIXct(paste(Date, Hour), format="%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="America/Los_Angeles")]
```

which results in:

```
print(EnergyUseAdj)

#         Date Hour  Power            Date_Time
#1: 1997-04-06    1     30  1997-04-06 01:00:00
#2: 1997-04-06    2     40                 <NA>
#3: 1997-04-06    3     60  1997-04-06 03:00:00
#4: 1997-04-06    4     80  1997-04-06 04:00:00
```

This, however, makes the "Power" data for the new daylight savings 3am and 4am incorrect.  The actual power production figure for the daylight adjusted 3am would instead be that which was listed for 2am standard time (i.e. 40), and that for 4am would then be 60.

The correct way to adjust for this, albeit likely more computationally expensive for large datasets, would be to adjust the entire time-series by a positive offset of 1 hour in spring and a negative offset of 1 hour in fall, like the below:

```
#         Date Hour  Power            Date_Time
#1: 1997-04-06    1     30  1997-04-06 01:00:00
#2: 1997-04-06    2   <NA>                 <NA>
#3: 1997-04-06    3     40  1997-04-06 03:00:00
#4: 1997-04-06    4     60  1997-04-06 04:00:00
```

Or, perhaps smoother for use in other algorithms due to lack of NA lines, like the below:

```
#         Date Hour  Power            Date_Time
#1: 1997-04-06    1     30  1997-04-06 01:00:00
#2: 1997-04-06    3     40  1997-04-06 03:00:00
#3: 1997-04-06    4     60  1997-04-06 04:00:00
#4: 1997-04-06    5     80  1997-04-06 05:00:00
```

After toying around with Posixct and reading through a bunch of similar questions on this adjustment, I could not find a great solution.  Any ideas?

EDIT: GregorThomas' request, see below for a larger sample of data in case you wish to use two days' worth.

```
#       OP_DATE OP_HOUR Power
# 1: 1997-04-05       0    71
# 2: 1997-04-05       1    61
# 3: 1997-04-05       2    54
# 4: 1997-04-05       3    57
# 5: 1997-04-05       4    68
# 6: 1997-04-05       5    76
# 7: 1997-04-05       6    89
# 8: 1997-04-05       7   106
# 9: 1997-04-05       8   148
#10: 1997-04-05       9   154
#11: 1997-04-05      10   143
#12: 1997-04-05      11   123
#13: 1997-04-05      12   105
#14: 1997-04-05      13    94
#15: 1997-04-05      14    85
#16: 1997-04-05      15    86
#17: 1997-04-05      16    84
#18: 1997-04-05      17    83
#19: 1997-04-05      18    99
#20: 1997-04-05      19   105
#21: 1997-04-05      20    94
#22: 1997-04-05      21    95
#23: 1997-04-05      22    81
#24: 1997-04-05      23    66
#25: 1997-04-06       0    75
#26: 1997-04-06       1    70
#27: 1997-04-06       2    62
#28: 1997-04-06       3    56
#29: 1997-04-06       4    55
#30: 1997-04-06       5    57
#31: 1997-04-06       6    51
#32: 1997-04-06       7    57
#33: 1997-04-06       8    59
#34: 1997-04-06       9    61
#35: 1997-04-06      10    64
#36: 1997-04-06      11    63
#37: 1997-04-06      12    63
#38: 1997-04-06      13    63
#39: 1997-04-06      14    60
#40: 1997-04-06      15    68
#41: 1997-04-06      16    69
#42: 1997-04-06      17    69
#43: 1997-04-06      18    91
#44: 1997-04-06      19   120
#45: 1997-04-06      20   100
#46: 1997-04-06      21    74
#47: 1997-04-06      22    56
#48: 1997-04-06      23    55
```

Comment: Could you share sample data from `1997-04-05 Hour 22` through `1997-04-7 Hour 2`? Is your data complete time-wise (1 row for every hour, every day)? I imagine you have the actually have hours 0 - 22 for the DST day in spring, and 0-24 for the DST day in fall, correct? Sharing an example of a fall DST day would probably be good too, assuming you want to handle both cases...

Comment: Where I'm going is that, if your data has the correct number of measurement, rather than adjusted you could generate a sequence of POSIX times by hour and tack them on, rather than doing any sort of conversion. E.g., `seq(as.POSIXct("1997-04-05 22:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1997-04-07 02:00:00"), by = "1 hour")` works fine (if you're in a locale that uses DST - we'd set it accordingly for generalizable code)

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for the reply.  There are exactly 24 hourly measurements (0-23) per day for the entire dataset, as it is in standard time (no DST shifts).  Therefore, the data does need to be adjusted to daylight savings.  The approach for the fall should just be the opposite offset as that used for the spring, as far as I understand it.

Comment: I think showing the complete days measurements, along with a couple from the preceding and following day would help things make sense. If your full year has the right number of hours, then adding on the `seq` approach as in my second comment should work just fine.

Comment: 24 * 365 = 8760. `length(seq(as.POSIXct("1997-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("1997-12-31 23:00:00"), by = "1 hour"))` is also 8760. Use `seq` from your first datetime  to your last datetime and let `seq` fill in the middle.

Comment: @GregorThomas That is a great suggestion. I had not thought about essentially just re-sequencing dates and times from the beginning of the dataset. I need to code in which years are leap years, or delete those values, but other than that, this should work.  I will test this out.

Comment: EDIT: @GregorThomas if you would like to turn your comment into a formatted answer, I will mark it as the solution. I tried it on the longer dataset I included above and it worked perfectly as EnergyUseAdj <- EnergyUse[, Date_Time := seq(as.POSIXct("1997-04-05 00:00:00", tz="America/Los_Angeles"), as.POSIXct("1997-04-07 00:00:00", tz="America/Los_Angeles"), by = "1 hour")].  The only hiccup now is how best to deal with leap years (I will likely cut the extra days from the dataset).

Comment: Sure - I'll write up the answer. Why do you think leap years won't work with this method?

Comment: @GregorThomas.  Thanks.  I had just assumed that Posix did not handle leap years, as the way it handled daylight savings conversion was strange.  Thankfully, I was wrong.

Comment: POSIX is literally the international standard for times - it may be strange (as daylight savings is strange itself), but it will certainly be accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is reliably every hour, you can calculate a sequence of hours of the appropriate length. The implementation of POSIX datetimes accounts for daylight savings time, leap years, etc.

Simplifying the method in my comment, I'd recommending calculating the sequence based on the start time and the length.

```
EnergyUseAdj <- EnergyUse[,
  Date_Time := seq(
    from = as.POSIXct(paste(Date[1], Hour[1]), format="%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="America/Los_Angeles"),
    length.out = .N,
    by = "1 hour"
  )]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer here.  This worked perfectly.  For those curious and not super familiar with data.table syntax, you can add ", by=.(Column1, Column2, etc.)" between the final ) and ] if you need to group the sequencing (e.g. each Column1-Column 2 combo has its own full set of date-times that need to be sequenced independently, like powerplants in the case of my dataset). Just make sure the data.table is already sorted by Column1, then Column2, then date, then time, in order to properly sequence when grouped.